# How to get event/Occasion name from date picker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uidatepicker

I want to know that it is possible to get event name from datepicker like if I select 25 december and get christmas as event name etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to create such functionality. You will have to create NSDictionary and Map date with event name. Whenever user selects any date then look it for that date in NSDictionary and get event name for that date.

This is one possible way. There might be other ways but please note that there is no predefined control to achieve this functionality.